# How to get permission response decision from keycloak authorization server

Tags: authorization, openid-connect, keycloak, rbac, kong

I am using [kong](https://github.com/Kong/kong) as my api-gateway and using a plugin [kong-oidc](https://github.com/nokia/kong-oidc) for authentication using keycloak. Authentication process is smooth and running fine. Now I want to add authorization for the requests made to kong for different microservices. I am planning to modify the `kong-oidc` plugin. I have created a `confidential client`, `role-based policies` and `resource based permissions` along with some users assigned with different roles in keycloak. I want to authorize a user if he has a permission to access a specific resource. I can do that by following request

```
http://keycloak-url/auth/realms/$realm/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer "$access_token \
  --data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket" \
  --data "audience=auth-client" \              
  --data "permission=af-resource" \     
  --data "response_mode=decision"
```

I am concerned with `permission=af-resource`. during the request I can not know the name of the resource but the requested url. Do I have to request to keycloak again to give me the `resource-id` for the `requested-url` and then send the above mentioned request for decision or there is another way? Or somehow i can use the information from `token-introspection` endpoint.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/476828/subodh-joshi any thoughts?

Comment: have you managed to get a Kong plugin to work with Keycloak's authorization services? I'm interested in doing exactly the same thing you've described in your question.